# From which host are names resolved for SSH tunnels?

Tags: ssh, dns, tunnel

If I am on `hostA` and connect to `hostB` with SSH, simultaneously creating a tunnel with the `-L` and/or `-R` options, and I specify the tunnel destination symbolically as `hostC`, who resolves the name to an IP address, `hostA` or `hostB`? Does it make a difference whether it is a local tunnel (`-L`) or remote tunnel (`-R`)?

This would matter if `hostA` and `hostB` have different views of `hostC`'s address.

That is, if I do this:

```
hostA$ dig hostC A +short
192.168.1.3
hostA$ ssh -L 1111:hostC:2222 -R 3333:hostC:4444 hostB
hostB$ dig hostC A +short
10.0.0.3
```

What address does `hostA` use for packets presented to `hostB:3333`? What address does `hostB` use for packets presented to `hostA:1111`?

Answer (score 0):

After a little tcpdump'ing i figured out that in both cases hostB resolves the IP-Address to the hostname.

I just started `tcpdump port 53` on hostA and hostB and tested the commands you provided.

For the second part of your question I can't provide an answer because the systems i used to reproduce what you provided in your question are hardly configured with IP-Adresses so I can't see any Hostname-Lookup (just a few Reverse-Lookups but I didn't mentioned to analyse them as they weren't part of your question)

Comment: I don't understand your statement about "the second part of [my] question." In the example, I give the IP address of `hostC` from the perspective of `hostA` and of `hostB`. The addresses of `hostA` and `hostB` are not significant.

Comment: Now i get what you meant, also didn't see the different hostnames in the prompt. I have to rethink this a bit.

Answer (score -1):

The resolver is driven by `/etc/resolv.conf` and other configuration files on the host where the requesting process is running.

Comment: Your statement is correct, but does not help to answer the question.

Comment: Flagged the comment as non-constructive as it doesn't indicate *why*.

Comment: My question is about the behavior of the SSH process---does it do a lookup locally and give an IP address to its peer, or does it send the hostname to the peer who then performs the lookup---but your answer describes how to configure a host to perform lookups for any process that tries to do a lookup.

Comment: Understood now. But that's easily testable and doesn't need a question on stack overflow.